# Put Azure RM value into a variable

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

When I run this code in a Azure powershell task

```
Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "****V2"
$storageAccounts = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "****V2"
Write-Host $storageAccounts
Write-Host $storageAccounts.value
```

I see:

[image]

The `Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "****V2"` returns the list, but the variable is showing empty. Is it not possible to store the return value on the variable?

Comment: where are you seeing this behaviour

Comment: In a Azure powershell task during the release

Comment: try write-output, instead of write-host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue, it should be like below.

```
$storageAccounts = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "joywebapp" | ft
Write-Output $storageAccounts
```

In the devops powershell task:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The issue was that I wasn't formatting the output from the `Get-AzureRmStorageAccount` method!